# Difference between both Translate elements in ABAP

Tags: abap

I don´t get it, what´s the difference between both elements in ABAP:

The old TRANSLATE element:

```
TRANSLATE l_value USING '" '.
```

The new translate element:

```
l_value = translate( val = l_value from = '"' to = ' ' )
or 
l_value = translate( val = l_value from = '"' to = space )
```

The old element works fine. The character is replaced by a space.

But the new one doesn't set a space, it´s shifting the text to left.

I don´t get it.. Do I do something wrong?

Another question:

I´m using the same code to replace `cl_abap_char_utilities=>horizontal_tab` to `SPACE`.

But how can I replace `horizontal_tabs` with the old `translate` element?

Answer (score 3):

It's mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abentranslate_functions.htm) of the translate function:

> *from* and *to* are character-like expression positions. If they have a fixed length, trailing blanks are ignored.

If you want to replace it with space, use a text string literal instead of a text field literal (see [docu](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenuntyped_character_literals.htm)).

```
l_value = translate( val = l_value from = '"' to ` ` ).
```

For you second question, to use the old *TRANSLATE* just concatenate the required values and pass the variable to *USING* or use *[String Templates](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenstring_templates.htm)*.

Comment: This other sentence from the documentation is also **essential** to explain the behavior of the `translate` function: _If to is shorter than from, the surplus characters from from are **removed** from the character string_. Less important: concerning the 2nd question, if the mask after USING is of type `string`, remember that the second character is to be a space but as it's a trailing character you must also use backticks `` ` ` `` to initialize the mask variable, or use a string template directly after USING (`TRANSLATE l_value USING |{ cl_abap_char_utilities=>horizontal_tab } |.`)